# Align numbering according to section in IEEEtran

Tags: sectioning, numbering, align

In IEEEtran, when I use align to number equations, they appear as (1), (2), (3), ... I want them to be (A.1), (A.2),... (B.1),... like the book format. How should I do this?

Comment: What are A, B,… in this context?

Comment: Basically it involves \renewcomand{\theequation}{...}, but IEEE will probably not appreciate the change.

Comment: Are you using the `IEEEtran` document class because you're preparing to submit a paper to an IEEE-affiliated journal? If yes, it's probably not a good idea to mess with the layout provided by the `IEEEtran` class. If no, why are you using the `IEEEtran` class in the first place?